# Recursively removing all elements from an array whose index is a multiple of i >= 2 (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm dealing with this recursion problem and I do need some assistance. I'm given a number n
and a length n,  sorted array r which contains only positive integers.
I need to remove every second element from the array, then third,...,nth element and so on until my array size is smaller then the nth number. then i need to determine if the given number n is a "special number", meaning it is in the final list after all required elements had been removed.
Not allowed to use any loops nor to create any other arrays but the given one.

for example: r = `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}`
after removing every second element: r = `{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}`
after removing every third element: r =  `{1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19}`.

after removing every 5th element: r = `{1,3,7,13}`

1,3,7,13 are special numbers.

Below is what I've done so far. for the above mentioned array r the program prints false.
What am I missing?

```
public static boolean isSpecial (int n ){
    int [] r = new int []{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
    int end = r.length -1  ;
    return isSpecialHelper(r, -1, end ,2  , n );
    
}
public static boolean isSpecialHelper ( int []r ,int start,int end, int i, int n){
    
    if ( i > r.length ){
        return isSpecialHelper1( r, i -1, n);
        
    }
    else if (i <= r.length && (start + i) % i != 0 && (start + i) < end){
        
            // r[(start+i)] = r[(start+i)+1];
            r[start+i] = r[(start+i)+1];
            return isSpecialHelper(r, start + i, i, end, n); 
    }
    else if((start + i)  == end){
        
            // r[(start+i)] = r[(start+i)+1];
            return isSpecialHelper(r, -1, i++ , end, n); 
        
    }
    return false;
}   
public static boolean isSpecialHelper1( int [] r,int j,int n){
    if (r[j] == n){
        return true;   
    }
    else if (r[j]!= n ){ return isSpecialHelper1(r, j--, n);}
    return false;
}
public static void main (String [] args){
   System.out.print(  isSpecial(7)));
    
}
    
}
```

Comment: Why this needs to be solved only with recursion?

Comment: These are the instructions for this problem, I didn't make those up haha

Comment: "the program doesn't print anything" Where do you tell it to print something?

Comment: Corrected my code

Comment: Arrays are fixed size. You can't remove elements, but you can copy just some of them to a new, smaller array...

Answer (score 1):

`isSpecial()` doesn't have a `System.out.println();` statement. `return` on its own doesn't print. You should do `System.out.println(isSpecial(7));` in your main method or add `System.out.println();` to your method. In this case you don't have to add return there and you can change method type to `void`.

Comment: Keeping the `return` and adding `System.out.println()` is preferred. This makes the method much more flexible by allowing the caller to do whatever they want with the return value.

Comment: In the current case it really doesn't matter. I just said that you can, but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: My bad. Corrected it. Now it returns false :/

Comment: Does it need to return true? I didn't check that.

Comment: @UnityGames000 In case it wasn't clear, my earlier comment was primarily for the OP and future visitors with a similar problem.

Comment: @UnityGames000 - Yes.